# Play mp3 data ( base 64 encoded mp3 string) on AVAudioPlayer with callbacks at different times?

Tags: ios, avplayer, avaudioplayer

I have to play a base64 encoded mp3 string and get callbacks at certain times so that i can do some operations.

I tried AVAudioPlayer initWithData and i was able to play that string but there is no callback method in AVAudioPlayer.

AVPlayer provides Timed State Observations but it does not let me play a base 64 encoded string as it does not have initwithdata method.

Answer (score 0):

Subject to your goal, you can observe timings at set intervals and within this callback optimise your logic to specific duration to act on.

Simply implement `addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval:queue:using:)` which will be triggered at predefined `CMTime` and trigger callback to execute.

Complete details with examples are in documentation

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/observing_the_playback_time

but including the snippet for reference

```
var player: AVPlayer!
var playerItem: AVPlayerItem!
var timeObserverToken: Any?

// Notify every half second
let timeScale = CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC)
let time = CMTime(seconds: 0.5, preferredTimescale: timeScale)

timeObserverToken = player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: time,
                                                      queue: .main) {
    [weak self] time in
    // implement your logic based on your required timings
}
```

make sure to keep a strong reference to any observer otherwise it will be released and no callback will be called.

Comment: Thanks Peter. But i have a base64 encoded string mp3 which i got in response of an API, Do i need to write that buffer into some file first because AVPlayer does not have initwithdata option unlike AVplayer has.

Comment: That’s correct. Use `FileManager` to store it to a file and use the URL.